# Could not update; currently locked. (VB6 and MS Access )

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2013

I'm getting the error "Could not update; currently locked." when two or more users insert a record in two different MS Access database files nearly simultaneously. What appears to be happening is that running a second copy of the code causes both databases to eventually become locked at the same time and each program is waiting for the other to release the locks on the table it was inserting into. So the first instance of the program goes into the error trap to wait for Logs.accdb to become unlocked so it can insert into the Logs table and the second instance of the program goes into the error trap to wait for Data.accdb to become unlocked so it can insert into the Transactions table. It is very common for us to have multiple computers running multiple exes. Each exe has two connections, one for each database. This configuration absolutely cannot be changed.

The production code uses substantially more complicated (and better organized) code, but I've reduced it down to the bare minimum to verify that code complexity wasn't the issue. I've created a test program that can recreate the error and have been unable to figure out any way to stop the error from happening other than switching the CursorLocation from adUseServer to adUseClient. This solution is unacceptable though because of the drastic increase in the time it takes to execute queries.

Things I've tried that didn't stop the error:

- Closing the connection after every insert. (In addition to not fixing the issue, this also caused drastic increases in the execution time.)
- Closing all connections when the error is detected and trying to Resume.
- Every permutation of CursorTypes.
- Replacing the ADODB RecordSet Update method for SQL Execute (INSERT INTO ...).
- Converting the Access 2003 database to Access 2013 and switching Jet 4.0 to Jet Ace 12.
- Creating a Front End for the database. (The databases typically reside on a network share with no Front End.)
- Moving the databases to C:. (I've read that long paths to the database can generate errors.)
- Changing the Client Settings within Access to do Row-based locking and changing All Locks to No Locks to Edited Rows.
- Edit: Add a delay in the error trap before Resume.

I'm looking for any help at all at resolving this issue without making drastic changes (like switching to SQL Server, which I've also tried and also resolves the issue but is also not an option). This is in production code for a very long-running company, so major changes are extremely difficult to implement (and also why there's so many 'requirements').

This is the code for the test program. The two WriteRecord functions are practically identical. Compiling this code into an exe and running two copies of the exe on the same machine always recreates the error.

```
Option Explicit

Public oLConnection As ADODB.Connection
Public oTConnection As ADODB.Connection

Sub Main()
    Dim RecordID As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred
    For RecordID = 1 To 100000
        DoEvents
        Transaction_WriteRecord "Joe", 40000
        Log_WriteRecord "Inserted Transaction", "Joe"
    Next 'RecordID
ErrorOccurred:
    oTConnection.Close
    Set oTConnection = Nothing
    oLConnection.Close
    Set oLConnection = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function Transaction_WriteRecord(TransAccount As String, TransDate As Long) As Boolean
    Dim rsTransaction As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim TryCount As Integer
    Static RecordID As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred

    sQuery = _
        "SELECT * " & _
        "FROM Transactions " & _
        "WHERE RecordID = 0"

    If oTConnection Is Nothing Then
        Set oTConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        oTConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Data.accdb"
        oTConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer
        oTConnection.Open
    End If

    Set rsTransaction = New ADODB.Recordset
    rsTransaction.ActiveConnection = oTConnection
    rsTransaction.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    rsTransaction.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rsTransaction.Open sQuery, Options:=adCmdText

    rsTransaction.AddNew
    rsTransaction!TransAccount = TransAccount
    rsTransaction!TransDate = TransDate
    rsTransaction.Update
    RecordID = rsTransaction!RecordID.Value
    rsTransaction.Close

    Transaction_WriteRecord = True
    Exit Function

ErrorOccurred:
    'If the error is that the table is locked because another user
    'is adding or deleting records, just try again.
    If VBA.Error(Err) Like "Could not update; currently locked*" Then
        DoEvents
        TryCount = TryCount + 1
        If TryCount >= 5 Then
            MsgBox "Could not update; currently locked. " & vbCr & _
                   "Table: Transaction" & vbCr & _
                   "RecordID: " & RecordID
            Err.Raise Err.Number
        Else
            Resume
        End If
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
    Transaction_WriteRecord = False
End Function

Public Function Log_WriteRecord(LogMessage As String, LogAccount As String) As Boolean
    Dim rsLog As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim TryCount As Integer
    Static RecordID As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred

    sQuery = _
        "SELECT * " & _
        "FROM Logs " & _
        "WHERE RecordID = 0"

    If oLConnection Is Nothing Then
        Set oLConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        oLConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Logs.accdb"
        oLConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer
        oLConnection.Open
    End If

    Set rsLog = New ADODB.Recordset
    rsLog.ActiveConnection = oLConnection
    rsLog.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    rsLog.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rsLog.Open sQuery, Options:=adCmdText

    rsLog.AddNew
    rsLog!LogMessage = LogMessage
    rsLog!LogAccount = LogAccount
    rsLog.Update
    RecordID = rsLog!RecordID.Value
    rsLog.Close

    Log_WriteRecord = True
    Exit Function

ErrorOccurred:
    'If the error is that the table is locked because another user
    'is adding or deleting records, just try again.
    If VBA.Error(Err) Like "Could not update; currently locked*" Then
        DoEvents
        TryCount = TryCount + 1
        If TryCount >= 5 Then
            MsgBox "Could not update; currently locked. " & vbCr & _
                   "Table: Logs" & vbCr & _
                   "RecordID: " & RecordID
            Err.Raise Err.Number
        Else
            Resume
        End If
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
    Log_WriteRecord = False
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a brief (maybe ~1 second) delay before the `Resume` after trapping the error?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "two different MS Access database files" since the rest of your post post suggests writing to the same table. Are you saying user1 opens Data1.accdb and Log1.accdb on the server and user2 opens Data2.accdb and Log2.accdb on the same server and then one of those users gets locked when **nobody else** opened the same 2 accdb files?

Comment: I have tried adding the delay, but once the code goes into the error trap, that's it; it goes in there 5 times in a row (it will go in there forever) because the databases both stay locked.

Comment: Logs and Transactions are in separate mdbs. The scenario is two programs (either two on one computer or one on each of two computers) each program has two connection objects and each connection object connects to a separate mdb (Data.mdb and Logs.mdb) which are in different paths. For the sake of the sample, the mdbs can be in the same path and the error still occurs. When the error occurs, both databases are locked and each program is waiting to write. So program 1 is waiting for Logs to be unlocked and program 2 is waiting for Transactions and they wait forever. Both programs throw the RTE.

Comment: Don't know if this is another "no-go", but have you considered using DAO instead of ADODB? Your code looks awfully convoluted, opening a "SELECT" recordset just to do an `.AddNew` with it. In DAO you open the database, then simply e.g. `Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset "table", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly + dbFailOnError` and `rs.AddNew`.

Comment: In ADODB, that initial query only serves to populate the RecordSet object's Fields collection. Because the adUseServer CursorLocation is selected, no data moves across the network to the client program when this call is executed. This is standard code for working with RecordSets in ADODB. In the list of things I've tried, I mentioned that I also converted this all to INSERT INTO queries that were executed on the connection object and that also did not resolve this issue. In general though, I have not tried DAO.

Comment: The files lock because it becomes read only. Try re-creating the code so only one person can edit the tables at one time. And the other person gets a message saying the file is not available at this time.

Comment: `the mdbs can be in the same path and the error still occurs` That I would expect since Access has known concurrency issues and why it should never be used for multi-user system. But the fact that this happens when the paths are different so each database only has a single user accessing it is quite puzzling. My gut is telling me that they are not really accessing on the separate paths as you think they are.

Comment: Only one person can edit the tables at one time. The error trap in the test code shows that when two people try to write it is capable of letting one finish before trying again. 

Modern Access databases do not have "known concurrency issues". This is a myth that has been perpetuated for decades. We have been using an Access database over a network drive in heavily-multi-user setups for many years on thousands of our customers' systems. We also use 5 different access databases. This error only appeared when we added a logs database that is written at the exact same time as the data database.